# How to prove the pullback lemma

Tags: category-theory

I am new in category theory. I am trying to prove the well known fact that if you have a commutative diagram of the form □□, where each square is a pullback, then the whole diagram is a pullback too, and hence deduce that the pullback of a pullback square is a pullback. Every book I have looked at has this as an exercise, but I (embarrasingly, I know) cannot see the solution. I have tried using the universality property of the two pullbacks but i am lost in calculations. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80612).

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98378/very-very-elementary-lemma-on-pullbacks-which-i-just-cannot-prove

Comment: You might also try posting your work up to the point where you get lost in calculations; then someone might help you find your way out again.

Answer (score 21):

[Just for you](http://math.andrej.com/2012/05/30/the-pullback-lemma/), and it turns out my answer has to contain at least 30 characters, so let's make it 100.

Comment: A question to whoever knows these things -- is it possible to include commutative diagrams in answers here, so that the external PDF isn't necessary?

Comment: That is a very good question.

Comment: Thanks for a citeable reference for this proof! Trivial nitpick: $m = m' = n' \circ f$ on page 2 should be $m = m' = f \circ n'$.

Answer (score 3):

My advice: try once more. The pullback property for the big square (or rectangle) really follows from the pullback properties of the two small squares.

Hint: Start with the right hand square. Can you see two arrows as in the condition of the pullback property?