# Checking $A\times_B(B\times_C D)\cong A\times_C D$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Consider a category has all finite pullbacks. I want to check $A\times_B(B\times_C D)\cong A\times_C D$.

It is clear from universal property of pullback that I get a unique map $A\times_B(B\times_C D)\to A\times_C D$ by stacking 2 pullback diagrams.

To get $A\times_C D\to A\times_B(B\times_C D)$, it suffices to observe $A\to B$ map giving the opposite morphism on the factor by restricting to the image of $A\times_C D\to A$ projection map. All only commutativity of diagram remains to be checked.

$\textbf{Q:}$ It seems that I have adopted element-wise checking approach for constructing such a map. Is there categorical approach to proving the statement without invoking element-wise checking?(Apparently, this procedure does not work over general category.)

Comment: You can check both objects satisfy the universal property. This should be straightforward by applying it twice to the iterated pullback.

Comment: You could also use Yoneda's lemma: for any object $U$, $\operatorname{Hom}(U, A \times_B (B \times_C D) \simeq \{ (f, g) \mid f \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, A), g \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, B \times_C D), \pi_{A,B} \circ f = \pi_{B \times_C D,B} \circ g \} \simeq \cdots \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(U, A \times_C D)$ as functors of $U$ implies that that morphism of functors is induced by a unique isomorphism of the form you want.

Comment: @DanielSchepler (That is more or less what I was aiming at, heh)

Comment: The Yoneda's lemma approach also has the advantage that it reads and is structured very much like a proof that the isomorphism works in a category of sheaves.  (Especially if you introduce the notation in a general category: $A(U)$ is syntactic sugar for $\operatorname{Hom}(U, A)$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Maybe this is a dumb question. In order to apply yoneda, do I need small category to make sense? It seems that checking universal property amounts equivalence of yoneda application. Do I expect this holds outside small category?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove the pullback lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151585/how-to-prove-the-pullback-lemma)