# Question on a specific pullback.

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading "A survey of Semi-abelian Categories" of F. Borceux and I'm struggling with a proof for hours now. I do not think specific skills in semi-abelian categories are required to help me here, just basic skills on pullbacks.[image]

The part I do not understand is "When the right hand square is a pullback, so is the left hand square". I can not prove it ... In another reference they use a metatheorem by just proving it in $\mathbf{Set}$ but I want to write it only with morphisms, in a categorical way. Can someone help me on this one ?

Comment: Kernel pairs are obtained as pullbacks; using this, it's just a matter of applying the "pullback pasting theorem" to the right diagram (try to draw a cube).

Comment: The cube I alluded to above is a bit like the one mentionned at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829677/pullback-of-a-pullback-square-along-f-is-again-a-pullback-square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
In the following diagram, both squares are pullback by assumption, hence, by [pullback pasting theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pasting+law+for+pullbacks), the outer rectangle is a pullback as well:
\begin{CD}
K[f']@>p'_i>>A'@>\beta>> A\\
@Vp'_iVV @VVf'V @VVfV\\
A'@>>f'>X'@>>\alpha>X
\end{CD}
In the following diagram, the outer rectangle (which is the same as before) and the rigth-hand square are pullbacks, hence, by [pullback pasting theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pasting+law+for+pullbacks), the left-hended square is a pullback as well.
\begin{CD}
K[f']@>\gamma>>K[f]@>p_i>> A\\
@Vp'_iVV @VVp_iV @VVfV\\
A'@>>\beta>A@>>f>X
\end{CD}

Comment: I can not think I spent so much time for this...  I should be able to find it myself. Thank you for the answer.